# Convert list of object into another object using map operator kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin

I have the following JSON data

```
[
{
"type": "carousal",
"items": [
  {
    "type": "story",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "grinning 1"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "story",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "grinning 2"
    }
  }
]
},
{
"type": "carousal",
"items": [
  {
    "type": "story",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "grinning 3"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "story",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "grinning 4"
    }
  }
]
}
]
```

Corresponding data classes are

```
data class ServerResponse(
@SerializedName("type")
val type: String,
@SerializedName("items")
val subTypes: List<ServerResponse>,
@SerializedName("data")
val data: Data)

data class Data(
@SerializedName("display_name")
val displayName: String)
```

This is the final data class I want the original object to be converted to

```
data class ConvertedData(val type: String, val name: String)
```

This is the kind of response I am looking for using map operator which returns a list convertedData object

```
[
  {
    "type": "story",
    "display_name": "grinning 1"
  },
  {
    "type": "story",
    "display_name": "grinning 2"
  },
  {
    "type": "story",
    "display_name": "grinning 3"
  },
  {
    "type": "story",
    "display_name": "grinning 4"
  }
]
```

I created an extension to convert the data as

```
fun ServerResponse.toConvertedData(): ConvertedData? {
val data: ConvertedData? = null
if(type.equals("carousal")){
    // compare subtypes type to "story" and put it converted data object
}
return data
}
```

The commented part I can't figure out since I need to go in the `items` array and want to use it as follows

```
val convertedData= serverResponse.map { it.toConvertedData() }
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could reindent the snippets properly

Comment: Have you checked the map function in the documentation? According to my understanding, this logic is incorrect. You will be reading a list of `ServerResponse` and returning a mapped list with `ConvertedData` items. Or You can do it one by one by iterating outside. But map function will help you do it. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#map

Comment: It looks like your initial data model for the JSON is not really correct, unless the structure of the JSON is way more flexible than it appears to be

Comment: You seem to be trying to convert a single `ServerResponse` into a single `ConvertedData` instance. You need to get a list of `ConvertedData` from a `ServerResponse` if you want to get the desired output. Also, if you're only taking the ones with `"story"` subtype, why do you need to store a `type` in `ConvertedData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` is generally used when each source item is converted to one target item.
If each item in the source list can yield multiple items in the target list, you should use `flatMap` instead.

In your case, a single `ServerResponse` instance can be mapped to multiple `ConvertedData` instances:

```kotlin
fun ServerResponse.convertSubTypes(): List<ConvertedData> = 
    subTypes
        .filter { it.type == "story" }
        .map { ConvertedData(type = it.type, name = it.data.displayName) }
```

Then you can use it with `flatMap`:

```kotlin
val serverResponseList = TODO("get list of server response from somewhere")
val result = serverResponseList.filter { it.type == "carousal" }
                               .flatMap { it.convertSubTypes() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the logic you have used is not correct, map won't be useful for your use case since map used to convert each item to a target item. Also in your case your json is a list of ServerResonse class.
use the extension function below, hope this will solve your problem

```
fun List<ServerResponse>.toConvertedData(): List<ConvertedData> {
    val convertedData:ArrayList<ConvertedData> = ArrayList()
    this.forEach {  data->
        if(data.type == "carousal"){
            data.subTypes.forEach { subData->
                if(subData.type == "story"){
                    convertedData.add(ConvertedData(subData.type,subData.data.displayName))
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return convertedData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have below classes

```
data class ConvertedData(val type: String, val name: String)

data class ServerResponse(val type: String, val items: List<Grining>)

data class Grining(val type:String, val data:Data)

data class Data(val display_name: String)

data class Response(val response: List<ServerResponse>)
```

Then try this function to convert it to required json format

```
fun Response.toConvertedData(): List<ConvertedData> {
val outputList: MutableList<ConvertedData> = mutableListOf()
this.response.forEach {  serverResponse ->
    if(serverResponse.type == "carousal"){
        // compare subtypes type to "story" and put it converted data object
            serverResponse.items.forEach {
                outputList.add(ConvertedData(it.type, it.data.display_name))
            }
        }
    }

    return outputList
}
```